# How to share a DVD drive on FreeNAS for Windows Network

Tags: dvd, freenas

I have added my DVD drive in the FreeNAS Web Interface (from Disks - Management). Now I want to access it as a Windows share (i.e. access it on my windows network) hence I tried mounting it but I keep getting an ***error - retry*** once its mounted.

How do I share this DVD drive on the entire network, as I want to allow network reading and burning through this drive.

Comment: What format/extension does the disk image have? ... And have you tried checking the error log?

Comment: @Wil its not a disk image its a physical dvd drive

Answer (score 1):

It's like a HDD, but you have to insert a DVD/CD first and you have to choose CD/DVD as file system for mounting or the error will appear.